# How to get function template taking invokables to match the types?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, function-templates

I have the following code intended to take a generic function object that takes two arguments and return a function object that does the same with the arguments in the other order.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

template<typename Function, typename FirstIn
    , typename SecondIn, typename std::enable_if<std::is_invocable<Function, FirstIn, SecondIn>::value>::type>
std::function<typename std::invoke_result<Function, FirstIn, SecondIn>::type(SecondIn, FirstIn)> 
swapInput(Function f)
{
    return[=](SecondIn b, FirstIn a) { return std::invoke(f, a, b); };
}

int main()
{
    std::function<bool(std::string, int)> isLength = [](std::string s, int len) {return (s.size() == len); };
    std::function<bool(int, std::string)> lengthIs =
        swapInput<std::function<bool(std::string, int)>, std::string, int>(isLength);
}
```

This gives the following compiler errors at the line assigning `lengthIs`:

```
Error   C2783   'std::function<std::invoke_result<Function,FirstIn,SecondIn>::type(SecondIn,FirstIn)> swapInput(Function)'
                : could not deduce template argument for '__formal' 
Error   C2672   'swapInput': no matching overloaded function found
```

I am using Visual Studio 19 set to C++17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of `std::enable_if` is wrong. You need

```
template<typename Function, typename FirstIn, typename SecondIn
    , typename = std::enable_if_t<
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    std::is_invocable_v<Function, FirstIn, SecondIn>    
                >
>
std::function<std::invoke_result_t<Function, FirstIn, SecondIn>(SecondIn, FirstIn)>
swapInput(Function f)
{
    return [=](SecondIn b, FirstIn a) {  return std::invoke(f, a, b);  };
}
```

**([See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3vG3qnfxx))**

---

**Suggestions**:

- Since you are using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), I would suggest a `auto` return for `swapInput`.
- One step further, if you rearrange the function template parameters, you do not need the verbose explicit `std::function<bool(std::string, int)>` at the function call.
- Using [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if), more easily readable code:

With the above suggestions:

```
template<typename FirstIn, typename SecondIn, typename Function>
auto swapInput(Function f)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<Function, FirstIn, SecondIn >)
        return [=](SecondIn b, FirstIn a) { return std::invoke(f, a, b); };
}
```

now the function call would be

```
std::function<bool(int, std::string)> lengthIs 
                               = swapInput<std::string, int>(isLength);
```

**([See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qY9vqEGcv))**

Comment: Thank you very much.